# is there a way to dump schema tables that don't exist and ignore the ones that exist?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

I am using this command to dump schema directly to a different server because the existing server don't have space left to dump the tables/schemas and then transfer to the other server:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u username --password='supersecretpassword' --set-gtid-purged=OFF --compress --skip-lock-tables --verbose schema_name  | mysql -u username --password='supersecretpassword' -h 192.168.10.10 schema_name
```

ideally, it should ignore the tables that already exist on the server `192.168.10.10` server.

thanks

Comment: you should try replication, you could select all tables off the second server and add this to the exclude, but you will need to programm that inqa aother language

Comment: thanks for your comment. what is replication?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to "pipe" `mysqldump` to `mysql`, where the two processes are talking to different instances of MySQL.  And that pipe could be run on either machine (with suitable changes to `-h`).  And there is no significant difference in performance.  BUT, you have not addressed freeing up the space on the source machine.  Was `innodb_file_per_table=ON` when you created its tables?

Comment: thanks @RickJames How do I check? These databases weren't created by me and I am not a DBA lol. I am a developer who sort of inherited this

Comment: If you would like to shrink / clean up the schema more, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further tips.